# Непонятный фрагмент кода

Tags: c++

Кто-нибудь может объяснить мне фрагменты кода, которые помеченны?

```
template <typename Return, typename... Arguments>
class Signal
{
public:
    template <typename Type>
    void connect(Type* o, Return (Type::*m)(Arguments...))
    //                            ^^^^^^^^
    {
        object = (T *)o;
        typedef Return (T::*M)(Arguments...);
        method = (M)m;
    }
    Return operator()(Arguments... args)
    {
        if (object && method)
            return (object->*method)(args...);
        else
            return Return();
    }
private:
    class T {};
    T *object = nullptr;
    Return (T::*method)(Arguments...) = nullptr; // <--------
};
```

Comment: Вас засмущал указатель на член класса? `Type::*m`? Вверху он передается в шаблонную функцию `connect` в качестве параметра, внизу - закрытый член-указатель `method`. Только вот лучше текст давать текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: а разве так Т::*m  не значит что m это статический  ?

Comment: Здесь нигде нет слова static. Это - указатель на член класса.

Comment: Мне кажется - сначало нужно почитать базу по с++, в данном случае какие бывают операторы - потом вопросов станет меньше. Вот одна из ссылок https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/126fe14k.aspx

Comment: я не понимаю в чем роль оператора : :  в Type::*m или T::*method ?

Comment: Замените, пожалуйста, картинку текстом.

Comment: Замените, пожалуйста, картинку текстом

Comment: Код основан на грубом хаке - поведение `operator ()` не определено.

Comment: (T::*method)(Arguments...) этот фрагмент не понимаю можно использовать указатель из другого обьекта как указатель на функцию в совсем другом обьекте ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `typename... Arguments` - произвольный набор типов, т.е. можно создать такой класс `Signal<Return, int, int>`, а можно и так `Signal<Return, Foo, Bar&, SomeType>`
2. `m` - это указатель на метод класса
3. Объявляем `method` как указатель на метод класса. Этот метод должен возвращать значения типа `Return`, а принимать список аргументов заданных шаблонным параметром `Arguments`.